# How to prevent axis label running through tick labels

Tags: charts, label, dc.js

I have created a chart using `dc.js`, and I havea a nice label on my Y axis. However, it is running through the number next to the ticks. How can I prevent this?

Code to create the chart:

```
chart
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(allCodes))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .yAxisLabel("Number of actions")
    .elasticY(true)
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(openActionCountGroup, "Open")
    .stack(closedActionCountGroup, "Closed")
    .colors (d2acolors)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(540).y(10))
    .title(function(d) { return d.key + ": " + d.value; })
;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely looking for the margins method.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/rRVgu/

```
chart
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(allCodes))
.height(300)
.width(300)

.margins({left: 50, right: 30, top: 0, bottom: 40})

.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
.yAxisLabel("Number of actions")
.elasticY(true)
.dimension(runDimension)
.group(openActionCountGroup, "Open")
.stack(closedActionCountGroup, "Closed")
.legend(dc.legend().x(540).y(10))
.title(function(d) { return d.key + ": " + d.value; });
```

You can change the left margin to give more room for the ticks.

[image]

Comment: This works well for barcharts, but unfortunately for composite charts, margins screw up the rest of the layout

Comment: Please [create an issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/new) showing the problem if margins are breaking composite chart layout.  They should work as long as the margins are the same for all the charts in the composite.